# mongoDB - how do i use projection and exclude a specific field with its value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this array in a mongo document:

```
"labels" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "4b19c495-8c40-4c92-8c7d-ae9fb8defd20",
        "labelCategory" : "Content",
        "labelType" : "Content_label",
        "code" : 5,
        "labelName" : "HR Request Forms",
        "trustValue" : 1.0,
        "riskValue" : 0.0,
        "sensitivity" : 0.2,
        "concrete" : 0.8,
        "threshold" : 2.0,
        "abstracts" : [ 
            "707babad-231f-82bb-014c-8506d3dc784e"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "707babad-231f-82bb-014c-8506d3dc784e",
        "labelCategory" : "Content",
        "labelType" : "Content_label",
        "code" : 5,
        "labelName" : "HR Information",
        "trustValue" : 1.0,
        "riskValue" : 0.0,
        "sensitivity" : 0.2,
        "concrete" : 0.2,
        "threshold" : 2.0,
        "abstracts" : []
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "9cdce502-1dd9-4ef9-b78b-7f7c638490bf",
        "labelCategory" : "Virtual",
        "labelType" : "Virtual_label",
        "code" : 1,
        "labelName" : "Object Low Sensitive",
        "trustValue" : 1.0,
        "riskValue" : 0.0,
        "sensitivity" : 0.0,
        "concrete" : 0.0,
        "threshold" : 0.0,
        "abstracts" : []
    }
],
```

For now all i have is this query:

```
db.getCollection('objects-89aafe20-780f-46ec-aaa0-a2d95bae542e').find(
{
    objectCategory:"Content",
    "labels":{
    $elemMatch:{"labelCategory" : "Content", labelName:{$ne:"Other"}}
    }
}, 
{objectName:1, _id:0, labels:{labelName:1}}
)
```

current output:

```
{
    "labels" : [ 
        {
            "labelName" : "HR Request Forms"
        }, 
        {
            "labelName" : "HR Information"
        }, 
        {
            "labelName" : "Object Low Sensitive"
        }
    ],
    "objectName" : "hr-L1-4.xls"
}
```

I am trying to fetch only the "labelName" which related to an object which include "labelCategory" : "Content" (**exclude the object that known as: "labelCategory" : "Virtual"**).
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `labels` and match both conditions, it will return filtered documents from `labels` array
- `$let` to declare a `labels` variable and above `$filter` will be inside labels, `$$labels` in `in` refers declared variable, `$$labels.labelName` will return array of string

```
db.getCollection('objects-89aafe20-780f-46ec-aaa0-a2d95bae542e').find({
  objectCategory: "Content",
  labels: {
    $elemMatch: {
      labelCategory: "Content",
      labelName: { $ne: "Other" }
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 0,
  objectName: 1,
  labels: {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        labels: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$labels",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.labelCategory", "Content"] },
                { $ne: ["$$this.labelName", "Other"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      in: "$$labels.labelName"
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/43ZxA8LSCoy)